# Excel VBA delete row dont execute vba script

Tags: excel, vba

Good day, i got a set of code as below:

```
Dim oval
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oval = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C1048576")) Is Nothing Then
Range("G" & Target.Row) = Now()
Range("H" & Target.Row) = oval
End If

End Sub
```

This is supposed to update column "G" with current date and time while column "H" with previous content in "C" should a change detected in column "C".
While this code is working, i got an issue whereby deleting a row of data in the middle of the table will shift the lower row up to the deleted row but it will update the column "G" and "H" as well.

is there a way to prevent that? thank you.

Comment: Have you ever selected more than a single cell? In those cases, Target is more than a single cell and `oval = Target.Value` will fail.

Comment: You have not turned off the Application.EnableEvents property but you write something to the worksheet. This would retrigger the event handler and the Worksheet_Change event macro would try to run on top of itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve **some** of your problems:

```
Dim oval

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    oval = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C1048576")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("G" & Target.Row) = Now()
            Range("H" & Target.Row) = oval
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the public variable and Worksheet_SelectionChange event macro. `Application.Undo` can be applied within the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro after recording the changed values.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range, vCEEs As Variant
        vCEEs = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value
        Application.Undo
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Range("C:C"))
            Range("G" & rng.Row) = Now()
            Range("H" & rng.Row) = Range("C" & rng.Row)
            Range("C" & rng.Row) = vCEEs(rng.Row, 1)
        Next rng
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This should survive pasting multiple values into column C but you risk losing values pasted into other columns.